# Bootstrap Different Time Picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap 3 date and timepicker below:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It is working great but I prefer the time selector from malot's version below:

http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I just wanted to know if there is any way I can integrate malot's time picker into the Datetime picker above that I am using.

Comment: i think you better to go for **eonasdan**. Bcoz if you need perfect time then  **eonasdan** usefull...

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it you have 2 options:

1. modify the source code to get the result you want
2. write a wrapper say in angular that manages both components that shows the eonasdan component for date selection and the malot component for time.

If I were you I'd just go with the malot component as there's little to distinguish the two where date selection is concerned :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for your input Kieran. I was thinking of going for the malot component but from what I know i think it is no longer being managed, so I might have to stick to Eonasdan until I can modify the source as you suggested :).